# How can I find collective anomalies for a data?

Tags: python, anomaly-detection

I have a data with timestamp and value. I need to find collective anomalies using an unsupervised algorithm.
[image]

```
#   DD  MM  YYYY    HH  mm  VALUE
0   14  02  2014    14  27  51.846
1   14  02  2014    14  32  44.508
2   14  02  2014    14  37  41.244
3   14  02  2014    14  42  48.568
4   14  02  2014    14  47  46.714
5   14  02  2014    14  52  44.986
6   14  02  2014    14  57  49.108
7   14  02  2014    15  02  40.470
8   14  02  2014    15  07  53.404
9   14  02  2014    15  12  45.400
10  14  02  2014    15  17  43.216
11  14  02  2014    15  22  49.720
12  14  02  2014    15  27  46.370
13  14  02  2014    15  32  43.756
14  14  02  2014    15  37  47.582
15  14  02  2014    15  42  40.738
16  14  02  2014    15  47  51.216
```

I have tried working on numeric data using multi stage clustering with X means. But the time stamp here seems to be confusing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share your data in numeric format? That way anyone that wants to tackle this problem can simply copy/paste the values, rather than having to type them from an image.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps clustering is not the best approach for this particular problem.
I'm a fan of keeping it simple whenever possible.

For your problem, I would suggest smoothing the data using exponentially moving average, measuring the rolling deviance, and marking an entry as anomalous whenever the current value is too far off the expected value.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average

This is your data (marked in blue) with the exponentially moving average plotted on top of it (alpha being 0.5). The advantage of using an exponentially moving average becomes clear, it allows the data to gradually shift, whilst dampening any sudden changes.

[image]

**What I would do:**

- sort your data according to timestamp
- apply exponentially moving average to get a continuous approximation of your curve
- when a new/next value is checked, compare it against the EMA
- if the value falls outside [EMA - std_dev, EMA + std_dev] then you can classify it as anomalous

**parameters to tweak:**

- alpha (used in EMA)
- use std_dev ? or perhaps multiply std_dev with some coefficient first?